# ifstream no matching constructor for initialization

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, c++17

I'm using QT Creator and MinGW (both latest versions) and am having trouble getting the ifstream to use the path argument constructor added in c++17.

Compiling the below code will fail with:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ifstream'
```

I've got `CONFIG += c++17` in my QT .pro file and `LIBS += -lstdc++fs`

MCV
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Lb3MNT

```cpp
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    const std::experimental::filesystem::path my_path = "C:/";
    std::ifstream input_file_stream(my_path);
}
```

Comment: This looks like just a declaration, which in itself should not lead to the error you mentioned. Please provide a self-contained small example, something that would compile (or produce a compiler error) on http://www.cpp.sh/

Comment: What happens if you use a `std::filesystem::path` instead?  `filesystem` is part of C++17 so you don't need the `experimental`.

Comment: Comes up with a filesystem not found error. I'm assuming MinGW doesnt have proper compat with c++17 filesystem?

Comment: cpp.sh cannot find the header filesystem

Comment: Makes sense, cpp.sh doesn't support C++17 yet. Perhaps you can do it on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ or https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler which seem to support it

Comment: A [mcve] that reproduces the issue (on QtCreator, at least) will help narrow the issue down. (Side Note: Also try `CONFIG += c++1z` in the .pro file.)

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Lb3MNT

Comment: Tried the config += c++1z, no change.

Answer (score 3):

@ user1406186, I replicated your same error, and was able to compile it applying the following changes to the `.pro` file and had to specify the `QMAKE` I needed to use:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

HEADERS +=
LIBS += -lstdc++fs
```

It also compiled with the following C++14/C++11 standards:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++14

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++14
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

HEADERS +=
LIBS += -lstdc++fs
```

Comment: Unfortuanley i'm still getting the same error. It must be the compiler?

Comment: Which specific compiler are you using? what is the output on your teriminal if you type the following instruction `gcc --version` ? also try to run this on your terminal and show the output `gcc yourprogram.cpp -o yourprogram`

Comment: version = gcc (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0

Comment: compiler output using gcc command 
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:12: error: 'filesystem' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 const std::filesystem::path my_path = "C:/";
            ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:6:33: error: 'my_path' was not declared in this scope
 std::ifstream input_file_stream(my_path);

Comment: Have you set the compiler on your `Qt`? : Tools > Options > C++ , Compilers, Add > MinGW
    In name put the compiler version, MinGW (version)
    It's the name that will be shown in Kits
    In Compiler path browse for the C++ compiler path, in this case D:\yourPath\mingw(your Version)\bin\g++.exe

Comment: Yes, i've added the compiler and added the kit and set it as default, but still same issue.

Comment: I get `does not name a type` and `was not declared in this scope` compiler errors with your [MCV on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Lb3MNT) but only *with gcc version 5.5 and lower*. With 6.1 and newer, godbolt successfully produces assembler code with no errors. This means the compiler version in your setup is still not correctly set. Try searching and removing any older compilers from your system to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string>
#include<experimental\filesystem>
using namespace std;
using namespace experimental::filesystem;
int main()
{
    path soure{current_path()};
    soure /="test.txt";

    ifstream input{u8path(soure).u8string()};
    if(!input)
    {
        cout<<"source file not exist"<<endl;
    }
    path dest{current_path()};
    dest /="test-copy.txt";
    ofstream output{u8path(dest).u8string()};

    string line;
    while(!getline(input,line).eof())
    {
        output<<line<<endl;
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: above solution tested with Qt creator and its working as expected